# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No query specified on getOne

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying create signup method in rest api, but I'm tired because of some problem with beans or query? I don't have idea what's is wrong.

At first I thought the problem was in the repository because the last error is "No query specified on getOne", but it looks good in my opinion.

RoleRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {
    Role findByRole(String role);
}
```

RoleRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

The second idea is wrong annotation but I could not find any irregularities. At last problem can be really easy because I'm starting with Spring

Whole project:
https://github.com/dextep/sms/tree/master/src/main/java/pl/popiel/sms

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'roleRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No query specified on getOne
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at pl.popiel.sms.SmsApplication.main(SmsApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'roleRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No query specified on getOne
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No query specified on getOne
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No query specified on getOne
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcRepositoryQuery.determineQuery(JdbcRepositoryQuery.java:200) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcRepositoryQuery.createExecutor(JdbcRepositoryQuery.java:101) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcRepositoryQuery.<init>(JdbcRepositoryQuery.java:90) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JdbcQueryLookupStrategy.java:69) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:574) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:567) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1052) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:569) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:332) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean.java:184) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted'''

'''
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'roleRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No query specified on getOne
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at pl.popiel.sms.SmsApplication.main(SmsApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'roleRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No query specified on getOne
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No query specified on getOne
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No query specified on getOne
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcRepositoryQuery.determineQuery(JdbcRepositoryQuery.java:200) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcRepositoryQuery.createExecutor(JdbcRepositoryQuery.java:101) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcRepositoryQuery.<init>(JdbcRepositoryQuery.java:90) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JdbcQueryLookupStrategy.java:69) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:574) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:567) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1052) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:569) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:332) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean.java:184) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Comment: It seems you're trying to use spring-data-jdbc using a JpaRepository. JpaRepository is for spring-data-jpa, not for spring-data-jdbc.

Comment: @JBNizet - My bad, you guided me because i include to Spring Boot project Spring Data JPA and Spring Data JDBC, and that was big mistake. My app didnt know what should to use. the solution was simple, all you had to do was remove dependencies from the pom.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

@JBNizet guided me because i include to Spring Boot project: Spring Data JPA and Spring Data JDBC, and that was big mistake. My app didnt know what should to use. The solution was simple, all you had to do was remove dependencies from the pom.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

I found this exception in my project but answer @JBNizet didn't work for me because i needed both frameworks for a while.
The problem was that Spring-data-jdbc tried to process Jpa repositories.

So my solution is to specify the unique path for repos in Jpa configuration and in Spring-data-jdbc config too, and they must not intersect.